# Can I embed the Matlab pop-up window for "Find & Replace"?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

When I type "ctrl + F" in matlab, I get the "Find & Replace" dialog box as a pop-up window. Can I somehow embed the pop-up window to avoid the annoying pop-up style? Most modern editors have a small embedded field showing up for search which I find much more useful...

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer is no.

Comment: that would be a pity...